# Get text after last number in alphanumeric string

Tags: java

I have the following string:

```
"Hard120109Missing or invalid shipper phone number"
```

How would I use Java to get the following:

```
"Missing or invalid shipper phone number"
```

Basically, I want to only retrieve the text after the last occurrence of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to get the last part of the String

```
String msg = "Hard120109Missing or invalid shipper phone number";
String val[] = msg.split("\\d+");
if (val.length > 1) {
  System.out.println("Message= " + val[1]);
}
```

Output

```
Message= Missing or invalid shipper phone number
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] arr = yourString.split("[0-9]+");

String newString = arr[1]; //get string after first number
```

First, split your string by any digits, and then get your string from array

For different amounts of numbers:

```
String[] arr = yourString.split("[0-9]+", 2);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (arr.length <= 1) 
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid String");

for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
     sb.append(arr[i]);
String newString = sb.toString();
```

Heres another way:

```
String newString  = "";
try{
    yourString.split("[0-9]+", 2)[1];
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){} //leaves newString as ""
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the string had more numbers, and would throw an error if there were none. Plus, creating an array for this is inefficient.

Comment: @russellsayshi 3rd option now more efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hard120109Missing or invalid shipper phone number";
String newStr = "";
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) break;

    newStr =  ch + newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always loop (assume this is its own helper method):

```
for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return str.substring(i+1);
    }
}
return "";
```